# What is a good introductory textbook to Laser Safety?

Tags: resource-recommendations, laser, laboratory-safety, photonics

I was looking for a good textbook about Laser Safety (e.g. protection glasses design, distance of risk calculation, laser classification...). I can't find a complete book with these informations, could you recommend one for me?

Comment: Wouldn’t the ANSI-Z standard be the go to document?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm focused on EU rules and I was looking for something which has some practical examples of evaluation of the basics elements (dimensioning of individual protection devices, safety distances...)

Comment: Fair enough. Do you have a laser safety officer at your institution?

Comment: Yes I have. I'm preparing an exam regarding laser safety, failed two times, because  material is very poor in quality and quantity so I noticed that also in the web is not easy to find a good point of reference for  what I'm looking for..

Comment: Indeed, the web in this case seems unhelpful. Good luck, I’m not up on EU regulations, so I’m not helpful either..

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how much regulations of EU and other regions are different, but I think different approach could be adopted regarding this matter. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

There's ton of material on internet regarding laser safety. Most universities and organisation have work manuals that are almost same w.r.t measurement of hazards and safety regulations/procedures.

Here you can find some good resource from top universities

- https://ehs.princeton.edu/sites/ehs/files/media_files/Laser%20Training%20Guide%202007%2013-08.pdf
- **Very detailed, also includes the examples of calculation.** https://www.ucc.ie/en/media/training/workthings/UCCLaserSafetyGuidelines.pdf
- https://www.ehs.ucsb.edu/sites/default/files/docs/rs/lasersaftyman.pdf
- **This one list the calculations in very simple and clear way.** https://d3qi0qp55mx5f5.cloudfront.net/researchsafety/docs/Laser_Safety_Calculations.pdf?mtime=1610127144
- **Most detailed, Military classified** https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/49543/jsp390_military_laser_safety_2005edition.pdf